# Visual Studio 2008 hangs while opening the solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a windows service project which I have created in Visual Studio 2008, sp1 with .net framework 3.5. The solution was working fine until today when I tried to open it again for further working and it just got hanged. Project doesn't get opened and just keep showing a waiting symbol. I don't know how and why did it happen. I tried to clear bin folder before opening but same result.
This project is not connected to any source control (TFS/VSS). Also other VS2008 projects get opened without any issue.

Could anyone please provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new solution, and adding the existing projects to it, one by one.

Also, you should put your solution under source control, and then you can easily track it's changes over time.  You could then revert any change that caused an odd error like this.

EDIT:

If you can't create new windows based solutions, perhaps you need to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: I agree on source control point. Also I guess problem is bit bigger/weird than I think, but not sure. When I try to create a new windows project/solution VS hangs and I am not able to work on it. Whereas I see my web application/website projects are getting opened but not windows based solutions.

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling Visual Studio?